Background Gradient Not Appearing in Obsidian with Custom CSS
I'm trying to set a custom background gradient in Obsidian using the following CSS snippet:
.workspace,
.markdown-preview-view,
.markdown-source-view,
.side-dock,
.mod-root {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

body {
  background-size: 500px 500px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #000000 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 1px);
}

However, the background gradient is not appearing as expected. I've ensured that the CSS is applied correctly, but it seems to be overridden or ignored.
What I've checked:

The theme allows custom CSS.
The CSS is saved in the correct file (e.g., obsidian.css).
No other styles are overriding my CSS.


It is not visible because you have used 1px in background-image its soo small that its not visible so try to use higher properties like 10% which I have used in below example ( See in full page view ).
If I have misunderstood or missed something then do share.


body {
  background-size: 500px 500px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #000000 10%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 10%);
}
<h2>
  CleanCodeEditor
</h2>



